# Python: writing over a new list with less variables

Tags: python, list, swap, overwrite

I'm having trouble thinking through this problem.

I have two lists as shown below.

```
my_orig_list = [(None, None), (None, None), (None, None), (None, None),(None, None), (None, None)]
new_values = [('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('c', 'c'), ('d', 'd'), ('e', 'e')]
```

How can I get it to have `(None, None)` as the final output as shown in the following desired output?

```
my_new_list = [('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('c', 'c'), ('d', 'd'), ('e', 'e'), (None, None)]
```

I should also state that the length of `new_values` will change from time to time.

I thought about determining the length of the list and then writing a function that would swap those values, but I cant seem to wrap my head around this relatively simple process.

If this has already been asked, I apologize. Maybe I don't know the terminology well enough to know what this would be called.

Comment: how about: `list(set(new_values + my_orig_list))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just slicing ***makes it easy*** ..

```
my_orig_list[:len(new_values)] = new_values[:]
```

keep in mind that
 `new_values[:]` copies the list i.e. make another copy of it,
whereas just doing.

`my_orig_list[:len(new_values)] = new_values`

will give a reference to it, both will work in this case as long as you don't manipulate the `new_values`, how ever i would recommend `new_values[:]`

Comment: Your idea of coping the values is wrong. Both variants do the same, but the first creates a temporary copy of `new_values`. So the second one is recommended.

Comment: thanks, you got me there, the iterate slipped from from my mind.

Comment: So, please change your answer, accordingly.

Comment: I'm voting this the answer. Although this isn't as easy to understand as Richard Stoeffel's answer, it's pretty pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through your new values, and use the index of the each array to update your original values like this:

```
for i in range(len(new_values)):
    my_orig_values[i] = new_values[i]
```

This will set the first value of my_orig_values to the first value of new_values, and so on, until the end of new_values

Comment: This works, and it's pretty simple to understand at first glance!

Answer (score 0):

May be below:

```
new_values.extend(my_orig_list[:-len(new_values)])
```